# facebook ios url scheme for swift4

Tags: ios, facebook, swift4

Does anyone know the scheme of facebook for swift4?
I have tried many ways and also these:

```
fb://profile/\(Username)! ,  
fb://profile?id=[username|user_id] ,
```

but redirects me to the wall of my facebook page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys i solved it using find my facebook id:https://findmyfbid.com and replace the companyName with id for the appURL

let appURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/1381815961922424")!

Answer (score 1):

First you should create app in facebook developers then get the app id and in info.plist replace YYYYYYYYYYYYYY with id of your app

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</string>

            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: this schema enables facebook to open your app not vice versa

Comment: use this https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=970860453059720 , and replace id with user id

Comment: login with permission opens it too  **facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions**

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: it will work if you have a valid userid i mean this is the structure of the url

Comment: the profile i want to show when click in my ios app is this :https://www.facebook.com/koulourades.gr/ It has no number id
What do i have to put here: let appURL = NSURL(string: "fb1381815961922424://profile/\(Username)")!

Answer (score 0):

I could only redirect to user profile using facebook user id. So the URL like http://facebook.com/816657065103305 goes to user profile

Comment: this is for web redirect!